# SQL Array concat agg with counts?

Tags: sql, arrays, group-by, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a table with arrays in it, and I want a new table with the counts of that array, but I need to do a group by.

```
ID  Arr
A   [1,2,3]
A   [1,3]
A   [3,4]
B   [1,2]
B   [1,3]
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
ID  Arr_element_counts
A   [1:2,2:1,3:3,4:1]
B   [1:2,2:1,3:1]
```

Note I tried something with ARR_CONCAT_AGG to make a multi-table, i.e. I made this with WITH

```
A  [1,2,3,1,3,3,4]
B  [1,2,1,3]
```

and then did counts from there, but it overloaded the available memory.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Arrays are *not* standard SQ.

Comment: It's a special version of Big table.  I made the arrays using Array_agg

Comment: If you are querying the table through BigQuery, you should tag appropriately.

Comment: I want to find a way to do the same as you but in order to stay in the same channel I want to know which version of big table are you using? And where are you making the query?